# Issue with Flask CLI Command Not Returning Control to Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

​I'm encountering a peculiar issue with a custom Flask CLI command that I've implemented. The command works as expected, but after its execution completes, it doesn't return control to the terminal, preventing me from running any further commands. I've included the code snippet below for reference:
​

```py
from src import app
@app.cli.command('test')
​
def test():
    print("test")
```

​
When I run this command using flask test, the command executes successfully, but the terminal doesn't regain control afterward.
​
I'm running this in a virtual environment and using Python version 3.10. I've also tested this on multiple terminals to rule out any environment-specific issues.
​
I'm keen to understand what could be causing this behavior and how I can make the command return control to the terminal after execution.
​
If anyone has encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into what might be causing this behavior, I'd greatly appreciate it.
​
Thank you in advance for your help.

I tried to run a custom CLI command on flask.
I am expecting to gain back the control of the terminal after the command is executing .
The command is successfully executed but I don't get the control of the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/) which ships with Flask (and is maintained by the same group behind Flask).

If you want to display (print) text to the cli, you must use the [`click.echo()` method](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/quickstart/#echoing).

```py
import click
from src import app

@app.cli.command
def test():
   click.echo("test")
```

[The Flask documentation also has very useful page](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/cli/#custom-commands) for making cli commands that fit nicely with your Flask application.